# Emacs 24 with Elpy 1.7.50 does not recognize Python Project

Tags: python, ide, elpy

***Note:*** This was initially posted [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29957437/1843248) a few months back and hasn't received an answer, but I'm reposting it since the Emacs StackExchange is now available.

I'm in the process of converting over from using Eclipse to Emacs 24.3 and Elpy 1.7.50 for my Python development.  However, I'm running into a roadblock in getting Elpy to recognize my project.  Based on my understanding of the way elpy should work from the [documentation](http://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html), if I set a project root folder, that folder should be included in the `sys.path` to search for modules.  This is not happening.

The [Elpy Documentation](http://elpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html) doesn't seem to have any answers to my particular conundrum, nor can I find a basic tutorial that walks me through creating my first Elpy project to break it down and show me what I'm doing wrong.

In the shell, I first create the virtual environment `virtualenv` using
`mkvirtualenv` from `virtualenvwrapper`.  Then I create the following
folder/file structure within the virtualenv folder:

```
virtualenv/
└─ my_project/
   ├─ src/
   │  └─ my_project/
   │     ├─ __init__.py
   │     └─ foo.py
   └─ test/
```

The contents of `foo.py` are:

```
class foo(object):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Next, I connect to an already-running instance of Emacs server using the Emacs client. Within Emacs, I enter:

```
M-x pyvenv-workon virtualenv
```

Emacs does show `[my_project]` in the mode line.  Next, I enter:

```
M-x elpy-set-project-root ~/Projects/my_project/src
```

Then, I type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> to search the project for a file, and I get:

```
C-c C-f is undefined
```

So, I type:

```
M-x elpy-find-file
```

and I get:

```
No project root found
```

If I create the file `test/test_foo.py` with the following code:

```
from my_project import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

and then run it using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>, I get:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/doug/Projects/my_project/src/test/test_foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_project import foo
ImportError: No module named 'my_project'
>>>
```

Comment: I think that project root is the directory containing `__init__.py` (the topmost one), not the `src`.

Comment: @wvxvw - I believe that this is one of the items I ticked off as I was troubleshooting this issue, but I can't remember, so I will try that again.  Thanks.

Comment: Another guess: iirc Ropes creates a special project file, where it stores project settings. I think elpy can use Ropes or Jedy back-end, Ropes would be the default one. I'm not sure it _should_ create a Ropes project, but if it does, can you look into it and see if there's some relevant info there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elpy knows of two "roots" for your directory, the "project root" and the "library root". The project root is used for file searches and similar, while the library root is the directory added to `sys.path`.

In your example, `my_project/` should be the project root, while `my_project/src/` should be the library root. You can verify this using `M-: (elpy-project-root)` and `M-: (elpy-library-root)` in a Python file.

But you opened a file in `test/`. For files in there, Elpy will find `my_project/test/` as the library root, as it does not know about `src/`.

Your best option is to use virtualenvwrapper's `add2virtualenv` tool to add your project – `my_project/src/` – to your virtauelvn's library path.

Hope this helps :-)